# HTML 5 table new row formatting

Tags: html, html-table, formatting

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody data-bind="foreach: collection 1">
  <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: Col1"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Col2"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Col3"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: Col4"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-bind="foreach: property">
       <td data-bind="text: Prop1"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: Prop2"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: Prop3"></td>
       <td data-bind="text: Prop4"></td>
  </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

I am iterating within collection1 and then for each item in collection1, I am iterating within property which is a property in collection1. I want every item in property to start on a new row.
Is this possible?

Comment: What language? Ans what is your current progress?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr data-bind="foreach: property">
   <td data-bind="text: Prop1"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: Prop2"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: Prop3"></td>
   <td data-bind="text: Prop4"></td>
</tr>
```

Just replaced above with :

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <table>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: property">
             <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Prop1"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Prop2"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Prop3"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Prop4"></td>
              </tr>
       </tbody>
       </table>
   </td>
 </tr>
```